# How to take Windows and Data Backup Programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

I need to take backup of windows data and its settings using C# code.

In order to achieve the goal I am running the following command:

```
Wbadmin start backup
```

[SOURCE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754015.aspx) of the command

**Problem:**

1. This command is not working with all versions of Windows.

**Request**

Is there any other reliable way to take windows data and settings backup.

Answer (score 0):

Wbadmin works on:

Windows Vista
Windows Server 2008
Windows 7
Windows 8
Windows 10
Windows Server 2008 R2
Windows Server 2012

That's a pretty standard recommended solution. What are you running into issues with beyond that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I regret to tell that  using [System State Backup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742124.aspx) does not work. is there any alternative for Wbadminother than Command line - CMD

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like Scenario #2 from:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742083(v=ws.11).aspx

```
wbadmin start backup –backupTarget:d: -include:g\folder1,h:\folder2 –systemstate -vsscopy
```

It would also be a good idea to take note of the syntax section

Syntax for Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008:

```
wbadmin start backup
[-backupTarget:{<BackupTargetLocation> | <TargetNetworkShare>}]
[-include:<VolumesToInclude>]
[-allCritical]
[-noVerify]
[-user:<UserName>]
[-password:<Password>]
[-noinheritAcl]
[-vssFull]
[-quiet]
```

Syntax for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 and later:

```
Wbadmin start backup
[-backupTarget:{<BackupTargetLocation> | <TargetNetworkShare>}]
[-include:<ItemsToInclude>]
[-nonRecurseInclude:<ItemsToInclude>]
[-exclude:<ItemsToExclude>]
[-nonRecurseExclude:<ItemsToExclude>]
[-allCritical]
[-systemState]
[-noVerify]
[-user:<UserName>]
[-password:<Password>]
[-noInheritAcl]
[-vssFull | -vssCopy] 
[-quiet]
```

You might have to detect the OS and run `wbadmin start systemstatebackup` in some scenarios. As you might notice, the systemState flag is missing from Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008. It's also important to note that `wbadmin start systemstatebackup` does not work on Windows 10, you will be greeted with the following message:

```
Warning:  The DELETE SYSTEMSTATEBACKUP command is not supported in this version of Windows.
The operation ended before completion.
```